# Choosing numerical method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

With a given ODE or a system of ODEs and I am going to use explicit Euler method and not $A$ stable and not isometric preserving one step Runge-Kutta method. How do I determine which method is better than the other when we apply to a ODE and a system of ODEs?

---

For an ODE, I think I need to look the order of consistency； for a system of odes, I think I will use explicit Euler method because it is $A$ stable. I am not sure I have a right idea or not. Any help are appreciated!

Comment: You can compute region of absolute stability and choose appropriate $A$–stable method of high order of convergence. You can also take into account factors such as difficulty of implementation of the method,  computational complexity, and required amount of memory.

Comment: Also, don't write integration methods yourself: try suites that are written by others first.

Comment: @Vlad the explicit euler method is better than the other method for ode and system of odes?